# Blender Handlers in Addon to trigger an IntProperty change

Tags: python, add-on, properties

I just learned that Handlers can be used to trigger certain events.

I have an *IntProperty* that is used as an index and when it changes I want to trigger a function.

I have been messing around and tried this:

```
def msgbus_callback(*args):
    # This will print:
    # Something changed! (1, 2, 3)
    print("This Function will do stuff When custom_index change value", args)

def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.custom_index = IntProperty()

    owner = object()
    subscribe_to = bpy.types.Scene.custom_index#bpy.context.object.location

    bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
        key=subscribe_to,
        owner=owner,
        args=(1, 2, 3),
        notify=msgbus_callback,
    )
```

However this does not work. How do I implement this in "The bigger Picture" that meaning my big addon that uses classes and such to change this *IntProperty* index frequently.
I want this to start running everytime Blender starts as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example which will create a panel called *Test Panel* where the addons usually appear with a *Number Stepper* (or *Spinner Box*) from the *IntProperty*. Whenever you change the value it executes the callback function named *update_value_callback*

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel, PropertyGroup, Scene
from bpy.props import IntProperty, PointerProperty

class MYTEST_PT_Panel(Panel):
    bl_idname = "MYTEST_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "MY UI"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Test Panel"

    def draw(self, context):
        col = self.layout.column()
        col.prop(context.scene.placeholder, "inc_dec_int", text="stepper")

class MyPropertyGroup(PropertyGroup):

    def update_value_callback(self, context):
        print("update value =====", context.scene.placeholder.inc_dec_int)

    inc_dec_int: IntProperty(
        min=1,
        default=1,
        step=1,
        update = update_value_callback
    )

classes = (
    MyPropertyGroup,
    MYTEST_PT_Panel,
)

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for c in classes:
        register_class(c)
    Scene.placeholder = PointerProperty(type=MyPropertyGroup)

def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for c in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(c)
    del Scene.placeholder

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I tried this and This is very nice. However my intProperty is not something that shows anywhere. it's simply put a variable that "keeps track" of the current value that is used as an index and the only way to change it is through various methods that adds and removes. this resulting in the intProperty in question to increase and decrease

Comment: oh. are you planning to use `bpy.types.IntProperty` or `bpy.props.IntProperty` ?

Comment: Hey I just realized the "update =  func" in the intProperty() from Harrys code. This was something i didn't find ANYWHERE. this solved it since it will jump to the assigned function when the property updates! All i had to do was to write bpy.types.Scene.custom_index = IntProperty(update = 'function') and it did the trick. Thank you

Comment: oh yeah, true it also has the *update* property! glad that helped :)